# Can I use part of MD5 hash for data identification?

Tags: language-agnostic, md5, hash

I use MD5 hash for [identifying files with unknown origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862346/how-do-i-assess-the-hash-collision-probability). No attacker here, so I don't care that MD5 has been broken and one can intendedly generate collisions.

My problem is I need to provide logging so that different problems are diagnosed easier. If I log every hash as a hex string that's too long, inconvenient and looks ugly, so I'd like to shorten the hash string.

Now I know that just taking a small part of a GUID [is a very bad idea](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/06/27/8659071.aspx) - GUIDs are designed to be unique, but part of them are not.

Is the same true for MD5 - can I take say first 4 bytes of MD5 and assume that I only get collision probability higher due to the reduced number of bytes compared to the original hash?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860405/are-the-first-32-bits-of-an-md5-hash-just-as-random-as-any-other-substring

Comment: I'm wondering if getting the first 4 bytes is better than using the CRC32 of the md5 hash.

Comment: Yes, because the first 32 bits in MD5 is supposed to be perfectly randomly distributed, so you can't improve the distribution.

Comment: @Nick D: Yes, since I already have that MD5 and it is controlling my program flow, while the CRC32 would be completely unrelated to it.

Comment: sharptooth: I meant statistically better. Andreas is right. CRC32 is pointless since MD5 was designed to has good random distribution across the whole 2^128-bit range.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is yes, you can use the first 4 bytes as an id. Beware of the birthday paradox though:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_paradox

The risk of a collision rapidly increases as you add more files. With 50.000 there's roughly 25% chance that you'll get an id collision.

**EDIT:** Ok, just read the link to your other question and with 100.000 files the chance of collision is roughly 70%.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a related topic you may refer to

[What is the probability that the first 4 bytes of MD5 hash computed from file contents will collide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727831/what-is-the-probability-that-the-first-4-bytes-of-md5-hash-computed-from-file-con)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to shorten the hash is to convert it to something more efficient than HEX like Base64 or some variant there-of.

Even if you're determined to take on 4 characters, taking 4 characters of base64 gives you more bits than hex.

Comment: only if you turn the hex into it's 0-F form. You can still take the raw byte values and use that instead. Which in that case would be more bits than base-64